# Initializer for 'Emgu.CV.MatInvoke' threw an exception in windows server 2012 OS?

Tags: asp.net, web, iis, emgucv

I am working on a asp.net web application.In my Web application i have used Emgucv .net Library. I published the web application and hosted it in my Local PC(windows 10 64 bit) using IIS, It's working fine. Same published code i have hosted in Server PC(windows server 2012 R2) using IIS. In server its throwing exception "The type initializer for 'Emgu.CV.MatInvoke'". How to resolve this issue in Server PC?

Comment: What about native dependencies? http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Download_And_Installation#Getting_the_Dependency If you don't have them on that server, the managed bits fail definitely.

Answer (score 0):

Emgu has a dependency on Media Foundation (MSMF) that is not installed by default on Windows Server 2012 R2.

This is described in EMGU release notes
http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Version_History

You have to add it, see https://github.com/emgucv/emgucv/issues/206